# Saving nested objects in Mongoose not working yet passing validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im seeing something very very unusual with Mongoose. Im using v4.8.1.

I have a schema called Gate and it has a property called `histGate`. I want to save data in the format:

```
histGate:{ 
    '4': 
        { 
            gateName: 'G1'
        },
    '5': 
        { 
            gateName: 'G5'
        } 
    },
    ...
    ...
```

So `histGate` will have property '4', '5', '7' and the values will be objects.

My Mongoose Schema is:

```
histGate: { 
    type: {
        "gateName": {type: String
    }
}
```

I can save a property to histGate once and when I check in Mongo I see:

```
'4': 
    { 
        gateName: 'G1',
    },
```

However, then I try to save another property:

```
    return Gate.findById(gateId)
    .then(function(gateDb){

        gateDb.histGate['5'] = gate;

        return gateDb.save()
        .then(function(gateDb){
            console.log('saved and gateDb is ', gateDb);
            return gateDb;
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log('err is ', err);
            throw err;
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('err is ', err);
        throw err;
    });
```

It tells me it has saved. `gateDb` has `histGate` with '4' and '5' properties. Yet when I look at the Mongo database, it doesnt, it only has the '4' property. And when I query, it only has the '4' property.

So Mongoose is telling me everything is fine and dandy and that it has saved, yet it actually has not. Whats going on? Is my schema wrong?

**EDIT**

If I edit a property that is a string, it works. If I edit a property that is an object, it works. When I edit a property that contains nested objects, it doesnt work

**EDIT**

It looks like this schema isnt possible with mongoose and mongo, it must be an array

**EDIT**

Looks like you can have dynamic keys, e.g. '4', '5' etc when creating a mongoose document, but you cannot edit them or add more. Totally baffling.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is detailed [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1204).

Fixed with:

```
gateDb.markModified('histGates');
```

Before the save.